# Convert date to string in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, date

I need to substract a string date by 1. so what I did was convert the string to date, substract by 1 day and covert it back to string. the last part I dont have no idea how to do it

```
string  date_in = date_in.Replace("\"", "");
//a string date

//new
DateTime my_dt = DateTime.Parse(date_in);
my_dt = my_dt.AddDays(-1);
//convert and substract
```

I need to convert my_dt back to string  before I can continue the process

```
//Date 
string[] date = date_in.Split('/');
int.TryParse(date[0], out Month);
int.TryParse(date[1], out Day);
int.TryParse(date[2], out Year);
```

Comment: Ahem... did you try `date.ToString()`?

Comment: You can just call `.ToString()` on the `my_dt` object. But if you're trying to access month/day/year portions, why not get them directly from the `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 2):

In .net 3.5 you can convert a DateTime to a string using ToString() and passing in the format as a string

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy");
```

Here is a MSDN link with formatting examples further down in the page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.90).aspx

Edit:

As PoweredByOrange pointed out you could also extract you string components without using the split method

```
var date = DateTime.Now;

var month = date.Month.ToString();
var day = date.Day.ToString();
var year = date.Year.ToString();
```